# Tkinter: Scaling items on a canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I was trying to understand how the scaling of canvas works.

Take for example, the following code. Why is that `canvas.scale("all", ...)`, which is bind to mouse wheel, is scaling all the rectangles and not the text as well.

How can I achieve scaling of text along with the rectangles?

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random

pressed = False

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400, background="bisque")
        self.xsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.ysb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set, xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,1000,1000))

        self.xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #Plot some rectangles
        for n in range(50):
            x0 = random.randint(0, 900)
            y0 = random.randint(50, 900)
            x1 = x0 + random.randint(50, 100)
            y1 = y0 + random.randint(50,100)
            color = ("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue")[random.randint(0,4)]
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x0,y0,x1,y1, outline="black", fill=color, activefill="black", tags=n)
        self.canvas.create_text(50,10, anchor="nw", text="Click and drag to move the canvas\nScroll to zoom.")

        # This is what enables using the mouse:
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.move_start)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_move)

        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-2>", self.pressed2)
        self.canvas.bind("<Motion>", self.move_move2)

        #linux scroll
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-4>", self.zoomerP)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-5>", self.zoomerM)
        #windows scroll
        self.canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>",self.zoomer)
        # Hack to make zoom work on Windows
        root.bind_all("<MouseWheel>",self.zoomer)

    #move
    def move_start(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)
    def move_move(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

    #move
    def pressed2(self, event):
        global pressed
        pressed = not pressed
        self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)
    def move_move2(self, event):
        if pressed:   
            self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)        

    #windows zoom
    def zoomer(self,event):
        if (event.delta > 0):
            self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
        elif (event.delta < 0):
            self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    #linux zoom
    def zoomerP(self,event):
        self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    def zoomerM(self,event):
        self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

The Scaling of text is not "really" a scaling of text. It is (at least with the `Canvas`-widget) a change of font.

From the [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html) :

> This method will not change the size of a text item, but may move it.

**Edit:**
This behaviour also applies to images (created with `Tkinter.Canvas.create_image(...)`) and windows (created with `Tkinter.Canvas.create_window(...)`). As the documentation defines scaling as

> **.scale(tagOrId, xOffset, yOffset, xScale, yScale)**

Scale all objects according to their distance from a point P=(xOffset, yOffset). The scale factors xScale and yScale are based on a value of 1.0, which means no scaling. *Every point in the objects selected by tagOrId is moved so that its x distance from P is multiplied by xScale and its y distance is multiplied by yScale.*

Please note the *italic* part for how scaling works.

**End Edit**

If you want to perform an increase of font-size you need to configure all the text elements by yourself using the `itemconfigure` method.

To Implement it in a very functional way you could use `tags` to identify all text elements. Increasing can happen not only absolute but also relatively if you first get the fontsize (`itemcget`) and then increase it depending on scale factor.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old but I solved a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721766/how-to-zoom-in-and-out-the-text-size-in-the-canvas-tkinter-python/68722985#68722985) so I thought I would post a solution for the problem as well.

The idea is to add a tag to the text item and then reconfigure it each time the zoomer is called. Note, this solution does not change the linux zoom (zoomerP)

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

pressed = False

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400, background="bisque")
        self.xsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.ysb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set, xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,1000,1000))

        self.xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.fontSize = 10

        #Plot some rectangles
        for n in range(50):
            x0 = random.randint(0, 900)
            y0 = random.randint(50, 900)
            x1 = x0 + random.randint(50, 100)
            y1 = y0 + random.randint(50,100)
            color = ("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue")[random.randint(0,4)]
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x0,y0,x1,y1, outline="black", fill=color, activefill="black", tags=n)
        self.canvas.create_text(50,10, anchor="nw", text="Click and drag to move the canvas\nScroll to zoom.", font = ("Helvetica", int(self.fontSize)), tags="text")

        # This is what enables using the mouse:
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.move_start)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_move)

        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-2>", self.pressed2)
        self.canvas.bind("<Motion>", self.move_move2)

        #linux scroll
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-4>", self.zoomerP)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-5>", self.zoomerM)
        #windows scroll
        self.canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>",self.zoomer)
        # Hack to make zoom work on Windows
        root.bind_all("<MouseWheel>",self.zoomer)

    #move
    def move_start(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)
    def move_move(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

    #move
    def pressed2(self, event):
        global pressed
        pressed = not pressed
        self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)
    def move_move2(self, event):
        if pressed:
            self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

    #windows zoom
    def zoomer(self,event):
        if (event.delta > 0):
            self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
            self.fontSize = self.fontSize * 1.1
        elif (event.delta < 0):
            self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)
            self.fontSize = self.fontSize * 0.9
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
        for child_widget in self.canvas.find_withtag("text"):
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(child_widget, font=("Helvetica", int(self.fontSize)))
        print(self.fontSize)

    #linux zoom
    def zoomerP(self,event):
        self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 1.1, 1.1)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    def zoomerM(self,event):
        self.canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, 0.9, 0.9)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```