# ARC on tkinter canvas glitches when zoomed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I ran into a problem with rendering an arc on tkinter canvas.
(I am using recommended methods for [scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795411/tkinter-scaling-items-on-a-canvas) and [scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645532/move-a-tkinter-canvas-with-mouse) the canvas, see my code...)

The code creates an arc on the canvas, its style is `'pieslice'`.
At first everything seems to work OK, but when I keep zooming-in to the curved edge of the shape, at some point it starts to mismatch with the other edges and eventually it disappears...

If I keep zooming even more, other edges disappear as well...

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
cnv = Canvas(root)
cnv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
cnv.create_arc(20, 20, 250, 250, start=0, extent=30)


def scroll_start(event):
    cnv.configure(cursor='fleur')
    cnv.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)


def scroll_move(event):
    cnv.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, 1)


def scroll_end(event):
    cnv.configure(cursor='arrow')


def zoom(event):
    if event.delta > 0:
        cnv.scale('all', cnv.canvasx(event.x), cnv.canvasy(event.y), 1.1, 1.1)
    else:
        cnv.scale('all', cnv.canvasx(event.x), cnv.canvasy(event.y), 0.9, 0.9)


cnv.bind('<Button-3>', scroll_start)
cnv.bind('<B3-Motion>', scroll_move)
cnv.bind('<ButtonRelease-3>', scroll_end)
cnv.bind('<MouseWheel>', zoom)

root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to fix this or am I getting to the limitations of tkinter? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer that gives a measure of the limit where scaling seems to break down:

Adding a variable to record the `scaling_factor`, I can reach a 336 times magnification before observing the phenomena described by the OP. I speculate that this is maybe a float precision issue, or a limitation of canvas size, or some other reason?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
cnv = Canvas(root)
cnv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
cnv.create_arc(20, 20, 250, 250, start=0, extent=30)

scaling_factor = 1


def scroll_start(event):
    cnv.configure(cursor='fleur')
    cnv.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)


def scroll_move(event):
    cnv.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, 1)


def scroll_end(event):
    cnv.configure(cursor='arrow')


def zoom(event):
    global scaling_factor
    if event.delta > 0:
        cnv.scale('all', cnv.canvasx(event.x), cnv.canvasy(event.y), 1.1, 1.1)
        scaling_factor *= 1.1
        print(scaling_factor)
    else:
        cnv.scale('all', cnv.canvasx(event.x), cnv.canvasy(event.y), 1/1.1, 1/1.1)
        scaling_factor *= .9
        print(scaling_factor)

cnv.bind('<Button-3>', scroll_start)
cnv.bind('<B3-Motion>', scroll_move)
cnv.bind('<ButtonRelease-3>', scroll_end)
cnv.bind('<MouseWheel>', zoom)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried making the arc twice as big and then the problem appears with half the `scale_factor`...

`cnv.create_arc(20, 20, 500, 500, start=0, extent=30)`